# Selenium Firefox Headless Connect Remote Debugger

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am running a headless firefox browser with Selenium.  If I run it in GUI mode then it works fine but when I run it in headless mode then I get an error about element being obstructed.

I really need a way to connect the Firefox remote debugger so I can see what is happening in the headless browser.

How do I enable remote debugging in selenium headless browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug marionette Gecko Driver by enabling trace logs and change the log level in order to get trace logs:

You can use FirefoxOptions in Selenium Java client to change the log level

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

For more information have a look at [Firefox Source docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html). More reading about debugging is [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Debugging.html)

Comment: I mean like when you connect to remote browser in debugger.  I can enter a port number and connect to it and it will give a console and screen preview